# Let $g(x) = \text{max}\{ f(y) \mid y\in [a,x] \}$, show that if $f$ is continuous then $g$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

> Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and define $g$ as follows : $g(a) = f(a)$ and, for $a < x \le b$ let $g(x)$ be the maximum value of $f$ in the subinterval $[a,x]$. Show that $g$ is continuous $[a,b]$.

**My attempt**: Clearly $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing function, so it cannot have discontinuities of the second type, and $g(x+)$, $g(x-)$ exists. So it is enough to show that $g(x+) = g(x-)$, as for a monotonic function $g(x-)\le g(x)\le g(x+)$.  Any hints on how to show that $g(x+) = g(x-)$ ? or maybe there is a different way to approach this problem.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2976140/42969.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n\to x^+$ a decreasing sequence. Let $f(y_n)=g(x_n)$ (such $y_n$ exist by continuity of $f$). Either there is $N$ s.t. $y_N\leq x$, and thus $g(x_n)=g(x)$ for all $n\geq N$, either $x\leq y_n\leq x_n$ for all $n$, and thus $g(x_n)=f(y_n)\to f(y)=g(x)$ when $n\to \infty $ by continuity of $f$.